# Why does $\frac{x^3 - 1}{x-1 }= x^2 + x + 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Thought about this for a while and it doesn't make sense to me. Obviously some rule that isn't appearing to me.

Prove that:

$\dfrac {x^{3}-1} {x-1}$ = $x^2 + x + 1 $

Similarly,

$\dfrac {x^{4}-1} {x-1}$ = $x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 $

At first I assumed:

$\dfrac {x^{3}-1} {x-1}$ = $x^2 + 1$

and,

$\dfrac {x^{4}-1} {x-1}$ = $x^3 + 1$

How and where do the middle terms come from?

Thanks to anyone that responds.

Comment: Just make polynomials long division.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take the equation: $\;\dfrac {x^{3}-1} {x-1} = x^2 + x + 1 \tag{1}$

If we multiply the numerator and denominator by $(x-1)$ (hence, not changing the equality), we get $$x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$$

To prove $(1)$, try proving $$x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$$

Now, to obtain the the quotient of two polynomials directly, we can use [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Comment: You're welcome, nitrous!

Comment: @amWhy: It is great that kind of feedback! :-) + 1

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the geometric series. Note that, 
$$\begin{align} S(x) &= 1 + x + x^2 + \dots +x^n \\
x S(x) &= x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots + x^{n+1}\\
S(x) - x S(x) &= 1 - x^{n+1}\\
S(x) &= \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} = 1 + x+x^2+ \dots + x^n \end{align}$$